# Suppressing Warning in Rescript: Js.Promise.make

Tags: unused-variables, rescript

When making a promise in Rescript:

```ml
let myPromise = Js.Promise.make((~resolve, ~reject) => resolve(. 2))
```

The ReScript compiler will give a warning on `unused variable reject.`

Is there a way to suppress this error?

Comment: I haven't used rescript, but can you just use `.make((~resolve) =>`?

Comment: `.make()` is a built in function from ReScript's JS API and it must take 2 named arguments `resolve` and `reject`. It is necessary to follow the format in ReScript or else the compiler will be unhappy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a parameter to a new name using `as`, i.e. `~reject as newName`, and as with any binding/pattern you can use the wildcard pattern, `_`, to tell the compiler that you're intentionally ignoring it.

So put together it'd be:

```ml
let myPromise = Js.Promise.make((~resolve, ~reject as _) => resolve(. 2))
```